# On duplicate key issue

Tags: mysql

I have a table for updating times for a game, in which columns are unique to avoid duplicates.

My problem is the following: how to update a particular column only and avoid inserting a new row if they are the same?

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad73b1/1/0).

I did this code and it still enters a new row instead of updating the `Time` Column only:

```
INSERT INTO `leaderboard` (`Persona`, `Level`, `Track`, `Car`, `Mode`, `Time`, 
                           `Date`, `Timestamp`, `HMS`) 
                           VALUES ('STIG', 80, 'SPA FRANCORCHAMPS', 
                                  'AUDI R8 LMS ULTRA', 'HD', '02:17.332',
                                  '2014-12-06', '1417825487', '1:24:47')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Time` = '02:17.332';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually creating a composite `unique` key in:

```
ALTER TABLE `leaderboard`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `Persona` (`Persona`,`Level`,`Track`,`Car`,`Mode`,`Time`,`Date`,`Timestamp`,`HMS`);
```

It means that the tuple `(Persona, Level, Track, Car, Mode, Time, Date, Timestamp, HMS)` will be unique. However, the time columns are to be updated, and it is very likely they won't be unique.

Maybe what you want to do is:

```
ALTER TABLE `leaderboard`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `Persona` (`Persona`,`Level`,`Track`,`Mode`);
```

Comment: hmm will see how it goes, I have made all of them unique for a reason.

Comment: Ok the problem was now the level, like in this example you can see, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27115/1/0 let's say he was level 79 and did a time and on level 80 he did another time thus inserting a new row still... but I have fixed it myself http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83ce97/1

Comment: @Lion : You should edit your question, so your goal is made clearer for other users as well. I will improve my answer in consequence.